# Looping using only two viewcontrollers - Showing userprofile of a follower of a User

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I dont really know what i should call this. I have made a app which has a profileviewcontroller of a selected user, and a button that will redirect to a new viewcontroller called FollowersViewController. There u can see all the followers a user has.

But this is what i want to accomplish :

Lets say you go into the profile of User A , then you check out the followers User A has. Then you see all the followers User A has in FollowersViewController. But when you click on say User B in the FollowersTableViewController (because user B follows user A), i want this to go back to the ProfileViewController , and to show User Bs profile. And then i can go into User B´s followers and click on User C , and i will be redirected to User C´s profile.

I want to accomplish this loop with only two ViewControllers (the ProfileViewController, and FollowersViewController)

Anyone have an idea of how i can do this?

I have used prepareForSegue from the SearchForOtherUser to show the right contents, this is the variable that holds the data for the selectedUser:

```
var selectedUser:[String:Any]=[:]
```

Comment: This should be a fairly straightforward matter of either a) when tapping on a user in Controller B, returning the tapped user's uid to Controller A to which it will then load the tapped users info. This can be done via a completionHandler. b) Store a reference in Controller B back to Controller A and when tapping on a user in Controller B calls a function in controller A that reloads the user and dismisses controller B. c) a delegate pattern but that may be overly complex for this task. Or... there's about 50 more options. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use delegate pattern to accomplish this scenario, add delegate in FollowersViewController and when you select a follower, call this delegate method and back to ProfileViewController then in ProfileViewController implement the delegate method to update user profile.
don't forget to connect delegate with ProfileViewController when show FollowersViewController
Try something like this:

```
class Profile: NSObject {
// profile data
}

protocol FollowersViewDelegate: class {
func didSelectFollower(with profile: Profile)
}

class FollowersViewController: UIViewController {
weak var delegate: FollowersViewDelegate!
}

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, FollowersViewDelegate {
var profile: Profile!
func didSelectFollower(with profile: Profile) {
    self.profile = profile
    // update profile data here
}
}
```